# Missing output values with different if condition for a particular variable

Tags: if-statement, sas, missing-data

```
data tt;
input init $ ht wt sex $ time @@;
if ht=. then short=' ';
else if ht<170 then short='y';
else short='n';
if wt=. then heavy=' ';
else if wt<80 then heavy='y';
else wt='n';
cards;
qqq 160.4 60.3 m 1 ewe 167.4 81.5 f 3 aqw 168.0 79.34 f 6
ccc 181.4 87.7 m 19 
;run;

proc print data=tt;
run;





output s like  this
init ht     wt    sex time short heavy
qqq  160.4  60.3  m   1    y     y 
ewe  167.4  .     f   3    y
aqw  168.0  79.34 f   6    y     y     
ccc  181.4  .     m   19   y`
```

I don't know why `wt` is having missing values. When I put `if wt>80`
then `wt(60.3 and 79.34)` will be missing and `81.5` and `87.7` will show in the output.

Comment: Your last line should also show "n" for "short" i think. I don't know the language to answer but pointing that out since it appears you may have overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the log, is there a NOTE that says "missing values were created .... "  and maybe a warning or error about a failed attempt to convert character values to numeric values?

Note the ELSE statement of your second IF block:

```
if wt=. then heavy=' ';
else if wt<80 then heavy='y';
else wt='n';
```

It should be `else heavy='n';`. As written, it is trying to assign the character value 'n' to the numeric variable wt. SAS will try to convert 'n' into a numeric value, and when that fails it will throw a warning or error to the log and convert it into a numeric missing value.